# Scilab unable to correctly read text and csv file

Tags: scilab

I wish to open and read the following text file in Scilab (version 6.0.2).
The original file is an .xlsx that I have converted to both .txt and .csv through Excel to facilitate opening & working with it in Scilab.
Using both fscanfMat and csvRead, scilab only reads the first column as Nan. I understand why the first column is considered as Nan, but I do not see why the rest of the document isn't read. Columns 2 and 3 are in particular of interest to me.

For csvRead, I used :

```
M=csvRead(chemin+filename,"    ",",",[],[],[],[],7);
```

to skip the 7-row header.

Could it be something to do with the way in which the file has been formatted?
For anyone able to help, I will try to upload an example of a .txt file and also the original .xlsx file

Files available for download, here: [Excel and Text files](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=cd1d7536-0d86-4b00-9b1b-6f4233da91d1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separator is a tabulation character (ascii code 9). Use the following command:

```
M=csvRead("Probe1_350N_2S.txt",ascii(9),",",[],[],[],[],7);
```

Comment: Thank you!
I had defined a tabulation in that space, but clearly it should have been ascii(9)

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your xlsx file into a xls one with Excel you can read it withthe readxls function.